# Chrome Extension: iframe injected into page returns null

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I've got a Chrome Extension that loads an iframe with some buttons whose functionality I want to control with a script. The iframe is injected and working.
When a user clicks the close icon, I want the iframe to close.

Here are the relevant files:
content.js

```
  // Check if the iframe has not been injected already
  if (!document.getElementById('extension-iframe')) {
    const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.id = 'extension-iframe';
    iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('iframe_content.html');

    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  }
}
```

extension_bar.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const closeIcon = document.getElementById('close-icon');
  console.log('Close icon element:', closeIcon);

  closeIcon.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('Close icon clicked');
    const iframe = document.getElementById('extension-iframe');
    console.log('Iframe element:', iframe);
    if (iframe) {
      iframe.remove();
      console.log('Iframe removed');
    }
  });
});
```

iframe_content.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extension_bar.css">
</head>
<body class="extension-body">
    <header class="extension-header">
      <div class="extension-logo">Your Logo</div>
      <div class="extension-icons">
        <img id="setting-icon" src="images/settings-icon.png" alt="Settings">
        <img id="close-icon" src="images/close-icon.png" alt="Close">
      </div>
    </header>
    <p id="extension-message">...</p>
  <script src="extension_bar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, I can't access the iframe using document.getElementById() and when trying to debug, the console returns ifram element:null. All the other elements are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iframe's inner contents is a separate different environment so its inner script (extension_bar.js) runs inside a different document. It can't access the outer document with the `iframe` element because the documents are cross-origin.

To remove the iframe you'll need to do it in the parent document in content.js:

```js
// iframe script: extension_bar.js
closeIcon.addEventListener('click', () => {
  chrome.tabs.getCurrent(tab => {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, 'remove-iframe');
  });
});
```

```js
// content script
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(msg => {
  if (msg === 'remove-iframe') {
    const src = chrome.runtime.getURL('iframe_content.html');
    const el = document.querySelector(`iframe[src="${src}"]`);
    el?.remove();
  }
});
```